# How to model ghamberson

Tags: modeling

I'm interested in the stitching and the cylindrical appearence. Not the garment itself. You see this sort of thing in blimps and the michelin man as-well.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's the best method because it has some flaws but anyway:

- Model all the big stripes on your mesh in *Edit* mode.
- Give your object a *Multires* modifier, subdivide 5 times.
- Switch to *Sculpt* mode and sculpt all the folds (*Crease* brush seems to work fine for this job).
- Don't apply the *Multires* modifier, bake the normals using the method explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0FwsMkWm0k) by Pixxo, so that you can keep a rather low-poly object.

[image]

Comment: Cool. I'll give this a go